# python как узнать id диска

Tags: python, python-3.x

как узнать id диска или пк на котором запускается программа?

Comment: Посмотрите этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4194146/13435478

Comment: Что конкретно вы подразумеваете под «id диска или пк»? У них у всех есть много всяких разных id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

используйте wmic

```
wmic diskdrive get model,name,serialnumber
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import os,subprocess
original_string = subprocess.check_output('wmic diskdrive get DeviceID', universal_newlines=True)
find_start = original_string.find("ID") + 2
print(original_string[find_start:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Отключить ПК от сети.
2. Открыть корпус ПК.
3. Изъять жесткий диск.
4. Посмотреть его серийный номер.